# Divider lines are not correct on Android 5 and Android 4 phones

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-appcompat

In my android application, I am migrating my app to "com.android.support:preference-v14:23.4.0" for my settings screen. I am using Theme.appCompat theme. Everything works fine on Android 6 phones.

But on Android 5 and Android 4 phones, I noticed that the divider lines are "black" in color. As I used dark theme, so they should be white (with some alpha). it is the case for Android 6 phones, but not for Android 5 and Android 4.

I tried a lot to change divider color but unable to do so. I also loooked for solutions on internet but nothin seem to work. Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the setDivider Method provided by PreferenceFragmentCompat class. That will change the style of your divider. 
But to use that method you need to be sure the view is created otherwise you will get a nullPointer error.
The best place to do that is to change the style in onViewCreated.

Example:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    setDividerStyle();
}

private void setDividerStyle() {
    ColorDrawable test  = new ColorDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.your color));
    setDivider(test);
    setDividerHeight(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using different themes for Android 6 and Android 5 (and 4).
Have you checked this?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use the same theme for all as I just have one styles.xml file for now.

Comment: What is the parent of the theme are you using? for example material go only on Android 5.0 or higher

Comment: parent of the theme is Theme.AppCompat. Indeed material was introduced on android 5.0 and above. Thats why I am using appcompat librray to support marerial design on lower versions. Most of the material design theme looks fine but the divider is not coming up fine.

Comment: Have you define your own color or are you using the default?

Comment: I am using default colors except the accent color which I have defined

Comment: try to define a "custom" white and use this.

Comment: I tried to define custom color for divider but it did not change. can you tell me how you suggest to change divider color?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116562/discussion-between-erik-minarini-and-sushil).